# Upload files with FileData Object

Tags: php, jquery

I want to create an uploadscript. This is my JS:

```
$("#subUpload").live("change", function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    var file = this.files[0];
    fd.append("subUpload", file);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      url: "script.php",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: fd,
      success: function(data){
        alert("Message: " + data);
      }
    });
});
```

And this is my PHP:

```
<?php
    if($_FILES['subUpload']['error'] == 0){
        if(is_dir('./files')){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['subUpload']['tmp_name'], '/files/'.$_FILES['subUpload']['tmp_name'])){
                echo"UPLOADED";
            }else{
                echo"FAIL";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Uncorrect Path";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo $_FILES['subUpload']['error'];
    }
?>
```

I always get the message "FAIL".
I've set the folder permission to 777.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can't see anything. Anyway, i want to understand what i'm doing, so if someone can tell me, why my code is not working, this will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

you need to give a name to that file not just the folder

see http://php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php

```
 (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['subUpload']['tmp_name'], '/files/'.$_FILES['subUpload']['name'])
```

if more problem check `is_dir('/files')` until you find the correct way to point to it

Comment: Didn't work as well. See Question above for updated PHP-script. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: i see 2 mistakes in your update : ./files in is_dir but not then after; then you use the tmp_name as destination but you must use the name ! do a print_r($_FILES) to see the structure of the $_FILES array

Comment: I've just noticed it. I used the name instead of the tmp_name, also i used ./files/NAME instead of just /files/NAME Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to give full path to destination folder. Not just `/files` but for example `getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'files'`.

Comment: Just to make sure: did you check ownership of your destination folder?

Comment: Yep, see: drwxrwxrwx 29 root     root        4096 Feb  9 11:31 files